# Create object of subclass

Tags: java, android

I have `MyClass mc=new MyClass();`, I need an access to subclass: `mc.Sub.Check()`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/488749/1234275 - doesn't work in this case.

```
public class MyClass {
  public onCreate() {
    super();
  }
  Public class Sub {
    public void Check() {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have an inner class. The link does not.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's not a related question.

Comment: Read up a little on java. First of all, `Public class Sub` should be `public class Sub`, secondly you are calling your super constructor from `onCreate()` you most likely want to call `super.onCreate()` if `MyClass` is an extension of `Activity`, although you are missing the `extends Activity` part. Third, if you want to access a method from a subclass like your example (without instantiation) you have to make the method static. Otherwise you would call `new MyClass.Sub().Check()`. And finally it is recommended that you follow the java naming convention and rename `Check()` `check()`

Comment: @Jave you're not right in a few things. It isn't an extension of Activity & I didn't miss it. I don't actually need static class, because I use this class only in one part of app. But anyway I thumbed up your comment. :)

Comment: @Jave also I solved it in this way: MyClass.Sub sub=new MyClass.Sub();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to create the Object of the Inner class like normal class. In above case you can do by following.

Sub sub = new Sub();

sub.check();

put above code Inside the onCreate();

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Solved: MyClass.Sub a=new MyClass.Sub();. I don't actually need it in onCreate(), because MyClass is big & I seldom use Sub. But it works too, accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate the inner class like any other class, i.e. `new MyClass.Sub`, then call the method. If you want to skip initiation you have to declare the nested class as static.

(Also: an instance of a non-static inner class can only exist in the context of an instance of the containing class).

Answer (score 0):

Only **Static** Methods are called with class name, either you make the method static or **create an instance** of inner class in outer class and all the method with the instance.