# Instance initialization block and subclasses

Tags: java, inheritance, initialization, initialization-block

I'm getting confused about when the instance initialization block should run.
According to Kathy Sierra's book:

> Instance init blocks run every time a class instance is created

So, consider having two classes: a parent and a child, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488727/inheritance-in-java-creating-an-object-of-the-subclass-invokes-also-the-constr) and java's documentation:

> instantiating a subclass object creates only 1 object of the subclass
>   type, but invokes the constructors of all of its superclasses.

According to the above: 
**why does the instance initialization block located in superclasses gets called every time an object of the subclass is instantiated?** it isn't like that a new object of the superclass is instantiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After compilation instance init blocks become part of constructors. `javac` simply adds the init block to each constructor, that is this:

```
public class Test1 {
    int x;
    int y;

    {
        x = 1;
    }

    Test1() {
        y = 1;
    }
}
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
public class Test1 {
    int x;
    int y;

    Test1() {
        x = 1;
        y = 1;
    }
}
```

So the init block runs when constructor runs.

Comment: Actually, there is a little more to it, the instance initializer blocks get added to the constructor after any existing call to a super constructor.  See http://java-blog.kbsbng.com/2016/01/instance-initializer-blocks-in-java.html for reference

Answer (score 1):

> it isn't like that a new object of the superclass is instantiated.

Actually, it is like that.

Every instance of a subclass implicitly contains an instance of its superclass.

A superclass constructor is always invoked as the first step in any constructor (and that in turn runs any instance initializer blocks for the superclass)

Comment: I know that all of the superclass constructors will be invoked, but what I understand is that regardless of invoking these constructors: only one object is being instantiated/created there, that is for the subclass.

Comment: You can look at it that way. But you could also say that the same object is also an instance of the superclass. And to be sure, the instance contains all the fields defined by the superclass in addition to its own.

Answer (score 0):

Though it was  a old post I came across this concept thought worth sharing it

Since we are talking about instance block here is how instance code flow executes in parent child relation class
// Child  extends Parent 
  If we create a object for Child

1) Identification of instance members of the class from parent to child

2) execution of instance variable assignments and instance blocks only on parent      class

3)execution of parent  constructor

4)execution of instance variable assignments and instance blocks only on Child class

5)Execution of child constructor

Answer (score -1):

Because there is always an implicit `super()` call(if not done explicitly) to the parent's constructor in the constructor of the child.