# Does object creation of subclass create object of superclass, if yes Is it possible to access it in subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

My question is if we can access and use indirectly/implicitly created super class objects when we instantiate a subclass .

Lets say `ClassA` is super class of `SubClassofA` and we instantiate `SubClassofA` in a client class `ClientClass` using `SubClassofA object = new SubClassofA();`

Since whole inheritance hierarchy gets instantiated when we create a subclass objects, I was wondering, is it possible to access object of class `ClassA` in client class?

If not possible, what might be reasons? Wouldn't it save lots of heap memory if we can access super class objects without recreating those?

I might have misunderstood whole concept of constructor chaining and inheritance hierarchy but please let me know your thoughts on this.

```
public class ClassA {}

public class SubClassofA extends ClassA {}

public class ClientClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SubClassofA object = new SubClassofA();

        //Above construct means that an instance of super class ClassA exists too 
        // If we can use those super class instances directly, will it result in memeory saving?
        //is it even possible to access implicitly created super class objects tied to subclass?


    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. According to the permissions on the methods.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Since whole inheritance hierarchy gets instantiated when we create a subclass objects, I was wondering, is it possible to access object of class ClassA in client class?

This is something lot of people get confused. If you create object of subclass, that ***does not*** mean it create object of super class.

Its just a call to constructor of super class, just to ensure that all the required fields are initialized in super class, ***but this does not create object of super class***.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488727/inheritance-in-java-creating-an-object-of-the-subclass-invokes-also-the-constr) will help you, understanding the concept.

> Check Kevin's answer:
>
> It doesn't create two objects, only one: *B*.
>
> When inheriting from another class, you **must** call super() in your constructor.  If you don't, the compiler will insert that call for you as you can plainly see.
>
> The superclass constructors are called because otherwise the object would be left in an uninitialized state, possibly unbeknownst to the developer of the subclass.

Comment: you mean to say in my questioncode sample, an object of type ClassA doesn't exist in heap? Only one Object of type SubClassofA  exists?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I will try to check in Eclipse JVM Monitor.