# Trying to understand super() behavior

Tags: java

I'm learning for my java certification and I came across this piece of code.

```
class Feline {
    public String type = "f ";
    public Feline() {
        System.out.print("feline ");
    }
}
public class Cougar extends Feline {
    public Cougar() {
        System.out.print("cougar "); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cougar().go();
    }
    void go() {
        type = "c ";
        System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
    }
}
```

And when I run it, I get "feline cougar c c " so I get why it returns feline and cougar after it but why super.type refers to a Cougar object and not a Feline Object?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767365/super-in-java) but it didn't really enlightened me.

Comment: In connection with super() call check this answer as well.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349164/does-object-creation-of-subclass-create-object-of-superclass-if-yes-is-it-possi/34349213#34349213

Comment: You changed the valud of `type`, so it got changed. What is there not to understand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super.type` is just referring to the same variable as `this.type`... there's only one object involved, and therefore one field.

When you create an instance of a subclass, it doesn't create two separate objects, one for the superclass and one for the subclass - it creates a single object which can be viewed as either the superclass or the subclass. It has a single set of fields. In this case, you have a single field (`type`) which originally had a value of `"f "`, but whose value was then changed to `"c "`.

Comment: Thanks pretty clean explanation :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is just one `type` variable. Your `Cougar`'s `go()` method sets it to "c ".
Therefore both `this.type` and `super.type` print `c`.

Answer (score 1):

this-> invokes current class :Cougar
super-> invokes Feline 
Feline is super class of Cougar because Cougar inherited from Feline. If you want to use Feline class fields in Cougar, You should use super.

You can see: http://www.instanceofjava.com/2015/03/this-vs-super-keywords.html

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add one more thing here for completeness

```
    public Cougar() {
        System.out.print("cougar "); 
    }
```

This constructor is translated by the compiler like this

```
    public Cougar() {
        super(); // Added by compiler if not added explicitly by programmer
        System.out.print("cougar "); 
    }
```

Thats why you get `feline` first and then `cougar` in output.
Other than that,there is only one `type` variable involved as explained in other answers, so it is printing `c` for both of them.