# Superclass printing unexpected value when Subclass is created

Tags: java, constructor

Could you please help in understanding the output of below java code where `this(0)` of `Superclass` is called when object is created for `Subclass`.

In this code though there is no mention in the code to explicitly print `20`, why the first value is printed as `20`?

```
class Superclass {
    Superclass() {
        this(0);
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    Superclass(int x) {
        System.out.println("2" + x);
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    Subclass(int x) {
        System.out.println("3" + x);
    }

    Subclass(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("4" + x + y);
    }
}

public class practiceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass s = new Subclass(10, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: "why the first value is printed as `"20"`" -> because you call `Subclass`'s `(int, int)` constructor. Within this constructor, you have an (implicit) call to `Superclass`'s no-args constructor. Within `Superclass`'s no-args constructor, you call `Superclass`'s `(int)`-constructor and there you print a `"2"`, followed by `x`'s value, which is `0`, producing the output `"20"`. Try stepping through the code using a debugger.

Comment: I don't get the down-votes. OP gave everything we need and explained the problem. Maybe it's because of *lack of research* but it can be hard to research if you don't know for what.

Comment: Besides the inheritance and object creation there is the String + operator question... So... not exactly a duplicate IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a constructor is invoked the first statement needs to be a call to any constructor of the superclass. If you don't call it explicitly, the compiler will add a call to the default constructor for you (As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488727/inheritance-in-java-creating-an-object-of-the-subclass-invokes-also-the-constr).).

In your case, the default constructor of your superclass calls the other constructor which in turn calls  `System.out.println("2" + x);`

This statement will print the string "2" appended to `Integer.valueOf(x).toString()`, resulting on the String "20" in your case (because x == 0).

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

### String *addition*

> In this code though there is no mention in the code to explicitly print "`20`"

Actually there is, take a look at your `Superclass`

```
Superclass() {
    this(0);
    System.out.println("1");
}

Superclass(int x) {
    System.out.println("2" + x);
}
```

*Addition* of `String`s is interpreted as **concatenation**, not as *ordinary addition* (of values). So calling the default constructor of `Superclass` triggers `this(0)` which yields

```
    System.out.println("2" + x);
=>  System.out.println("2" + 0);
=>  System.out.println("20");
```

thus printing `20`.

---

### Integer *addition*

If you want to add the values as **integer** you need to use `int` values and **not** `String` values, for example like

```
Superclass(int x) {
    System.out.println(2 + x);
}
```

then you will also get

```
    System.out.println(2 + x);
=>  System.out.println(2 + 0);
=>  System.out.println(2);
```

---

### Constructor-chain

Okay, so what happens exactly if you call

```
Subclass s = new Subclass(10, 20);
```

Well, first, of course, you trigger this constructor

```
Subclass(int x, int y) {
    System.out.println("4" + x + y);
}
```

Now in Java, when creating sub-classes you will **always** need to call one of the constructors of the super-class (it's per definition of the language).

And if you don't explicitly specify such a call then it tries to call the **default constructor** of your super-class. If there is no, it won't compile. However you have such a default constructor, the code will thus be equivalent to

```
Subclass(int x, int y) {
    // Implicit call of default super-constructor
    super();
    System.out.println("4" + x + y);
}
```

So you call the following constructor

```
Superclass() {
    this(0);
    System.out.println("1");
}
```

which, as shown above, triggers the other constructor

```
Superclass(int x) {
    System.out.println("2" + x);
}
```

So what you will get, if resolving this chain, are the following outputs

```
// from Superclass(int x)
System.out.println("2" + 0);
// from Superclass()
System.out.println("1");
// from Subclass(int x, int y)
System.out.println("4" + 10 + 20);
```

which yields

```
20
1
41020
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the detail explanation and It’s Cristal clearly.