# Does creating an instance of a subclass, create an instance of it's parent class in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have a main class `Vehicle` and it's sub class `Car`. If i create an instance of car like:

```
Car honda = new Car();
```

Does this also create and instance of the `Vehicle` class aswell?

Comment: Well I have the class Vehicle, which contains some methods which all of it's subclasses will use. For now I'm just testing my Car class and was wondering, if a Vehicle instance is also created since Car uses some methods of Vehicle.

Comment: Create object like `Vehicle honda = new Car();`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/488727/11200630) help you?

Comment: Yeah, it explains it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `new Car()` will create a single `Car` instance. Since Car is a subclass of Vehicle, this instance is itself also a Vehicle instance. In particular, your Car instance will have all methods of the Vehicle class.

So, the answer to your question is: Yes, a Vehicle instance is created. But this is the same instance as the Car instance.